# How do I pass all other attributes in props - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-component

```
const Label = (props) => {
  return <label className={"card-label"} {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</label>;
};
```

If I try to access the attributes in other functions. I'm getting errors and unable to proceed

```
<Label attributes={style:{margin:"10px"}}>Select Tip %</Label>
```

Does anyone know the answer? How do I pass all other attributes of any component with props?

Comment: Generally when you see errors it's worth including the error message in the question.

Comment: @DBS - I forgot to add the error message. Next time I will definitely add the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your attributes value into attributes prop as an object:

```js
return <Label className={"card-label"} attributes={{style:{}}}>Select Tip %</Label>;
```

A more readable way is to extract attributes from props directly:

```js
const Label = ({ attributes, children }) => {
  return <label className={"card-label"} {...attributes}>{children}</label>;
};
```

Comment: how do I pass all other attributes for example style,htmlfor as a single prop for the functional component

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `<label attributes={props.attributes} />` ?

Comment: It should be <label {...props.attribute} /> and <Label attributes={{...attributes}} /> I've mistaked the label with Label

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a issue with the syntax of passing props to Label component .Try with this

```
const Label = (props) => {
    return <label className={"card-label"} {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</label>;
  };

  return <Label attributes={{style:{margin:"50px"}}}>Select Tip %</Label>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code. I found the error.

Comment: @SambenJerald But why did you accept the other answer (which is wrong btw).